# Wordpress: Select a sub category for a post, and show it on the main category

Tags: wordpress, post, categories

I have on my wordpress these categories :

```
  - Main Category
     - Sub Category
  - Another Category
```

Then I create a post with only "Sub Category" selected.

When I'm showing the "Main Category" content, the post doesn't appear, so is there any solution to show all sub categories posts on the main category?

Thank's!

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use this function:

```
wp_list_categories( $args );

$args = array(
'show_option_all'    => '',
'orderby'            => 'name',
'order'              => 'ASC',
'style'              => 'list',
'show_count'         => 0,
'hide_empty'         => 1,
'use_desc_for_title' => 1,
'child_of'           => 0,
'feed'               => '',
'feed_type'          => '',
'feed_image'         => '',
'exclude'            => '',
'exclude_tree'       => '',
'include'            => '',
'hierarchical'       => 1,
'title_li'           => __( 'Categories' ),
'show_option_none'   => __( 'No categories' ),
'number'             => null,
'echo'               => 1,
'depth'              => 0,
'current_category'   => 0,
'pad_counts'         => 0,
'taxonomy'           => 'category',
'walker'             => null
);
```

Link: http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_categories

Comment: I think you don't understand my request, what I search to show is "posts" and not "sub categories". Please tell me if you want more informations. And thank's for your help :)